# Vanilla JS: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, import, html5-canvas, export

Im new to stack overflow. I am starting to make a game and i have a problem. I want to split my work into separate files so its easier. But i encountered a problem :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

This is the error i get with this code:

main.js:

```
import Player from './modules/player';

window.addEventListener('load', main);

function main() {
    let canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function loadImg(src) {
        let output = new Image();
        output.src = src;
        return output;
    }

    let player = new Player(loadImg('spaceship.png'), 20, 50, 80, 80);

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.height);
        ///
        player.draw();
        ///
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
}
```

modules/player.js:

```
export default class Player {
    constructor(cw, ch, sx, sy, img) {
        this.cw = cw;
        this.ch = ch;
        this.sx = sx;
        this.sy = sy;
        this.img = img;
    }

    // DRAWING
    draw() {
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.sx, this.sy);
    }
    fill() {
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.sx, this.sy);
    }
    stroke() {
        ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.sx, this.sy);
    }
    ///

    shoot() {}
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pucalka - Remastered</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas width="800" height="600" id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The error message should be pretty clear: you have to explicitly tell the browser that your JavaScript file is a **module** by adding `type=module` to the `<script>` tag.

Comment: But then (because im using vscode live server) im getting this error: GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/modules/player net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Well that means that your module to be imported is not where the code says it is, or that its name is different.

Comment: nvm i fixed it. changed "from '.modules/player" to "from .modules/player.js"